# Specifying Python statements using Unicode Code Points

Tags: python, parsing, unicode

I am trying to understand the python parser on how it handles the source code text and how it tokenizes while parsing. I have 3 statements in the same source file , essentially doing the same function.

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
print("This is a Unicode List")
eval("\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0028\u0022This is a Unicode List\u0022\u0029")
\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0028\u0022This is a Unicode List\u0022\u0029
```

The first 2 lines works as expected however I get a syntax error for line 3

```
File "...\UnicodeInput.py", line 4
    \u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0028\u0022This is a Unicode List\u0022\u0029
                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

is there a way for me to provide python statements with its equivalent codepoints

Comment: Line 4 is not valid Python syntax

Comment: Python allows escape sequences only in string literals.

Answer (score 1):

No, Python won't allow escape sequences as valid source code, they only make sense inside strings.  Backslash is the line continuation character in Python source.   The only way you can do what you want is to use eval or generate the python file by using another python script using the escape sequences.